# Dapper Method not found exception

Tags: c#, dapper

```
using (var conn = _config.OpenConnection())
            {
                var p = new DynamicParameters();
                p.Add("@playerName",playerName);
```

It worked previously in earlier versions well but last dapper version 1.40.0.0 returns strange error :

> Result Message:  Test method
>   DupGames.Database.DbAccess.Tests.BlackjackDbTests.SelectNewDealTest
>   threw exception:  System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'Void Dapper.DynamicParameters.Add(System.String, System.Object,
>   System.Nullable`1<System.Data.DbType>,
>   System.Nullable`1,
>   System.Nullable`1<Int32>, System.Nullable`1,
>   System.Nullable`1)'.

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2004/02/13/debugging-a-missingmethodexception-missingfieldexception-typeloadexception.aspx

Comment: Thanks for quick reply bt Not able to help something.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem occured due to the version mismatch.

Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem. Accidentally nuget'd Dapper.Async which uses an old version of Dapper and linked to another library that uses a newer version. Even though I was tracing with fuslogvw the version mismatch wasn't obvious.

Answer (score 10):

For the benefit of others finding this via Google: it's possible that you have a static property in your model. See [this bug](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/621) for details.

Comment: Exactly this. Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer.